# 3D Graphics Algorithms (Hardware)

Tags: graphics, matrix, hardware, gpu

I am trying to design an asic graphics processor. I have done extensive research on the topic but I am still kind of fuzzy on how to translate and rotate points. I am using orthographic projection to rasterize the transformed points.

I have been using the following lecture regarding the matrix multiplication (homogenous coordinates)
http://www.cs.kent.edu/~zhao/gpu/lectures/Transformation.pdf

Could someone please explain this a little more in depth to me. I am still somewhat shakey on the algorithm. I am passing a camera (x,y,z) and a camera vector (x,y,z) representing the camera angle, along with a point (x,y,z). What should go where within the matrices to transform the point to the new appropriate location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete transformation algorithm in pseudocode:

```
void project(Vec3d objPos, Matrix4d modelViewMatrix,
    Matrix4d projMatrix, Rect viewport, Vec3d& winCoords)
{
    Vec4d in(objPos.x, objPos.y, objPos.z, 1.0);
    in = projMatrix * modelViewMatrix * in;
    in /= in.w; // perspective division
    // "in" is now in normalized device coordinates, which are in the range [-1, 1].

    // Map coordinates to range [0, 1]
    in.x = in.x / 2 + 0.5;    
    in.y = in.y / 2 + 0.5;    
    in.z = in.z / 2 + 0.5;    

    // Map to viewport
    winCoords.x = in.x * viewport.w + viewport.x;    
    winCoords.y = in.y * viewport.h + viewport.y;    
    winCoords.z = in.z;    
}
```

Then rasterize using winCoords.x and winCoords.y.

For an explanation of the stages of this algorithm, see question 9.011 from the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm).

Comment: I don't know any opengl, I am only trying to implement this in hardware. Could you explain the modelviewmatrix, and projection matrix. I will be receiving a camera angle (vector) and camera location (vertex). How do these generate the modelviewmatrix and projection matrix?

Comment: Also would the modelViewMatrix be the rotation matrix and the projection matrix be the translation matrix?

Comment: @Steve: the "model view" is a combination of the "model" and "view" transforms; the model transform shifts model space to world space, and the view transform shifts world space to eye space. You should read up on OpenGL, it tries to model 3D hardware in software so knowing it gives you a good idea of how such hardware can work.

Comment: @Steve: As unwind said, modelView is the combination of the view (camera) transform and the model transform, although in your case there is no model transform, so you can think of modelView as the matrix representing your camera transform. So in your case the modelView is a combination of translation and rotation. You can generate your modelView matrix by creating a translation matrix, then creating a rotation matrix, then multiplying those two together.

Comment: @Steve: As to the proj matrix, it's unrelated to the camera direction & position. It basically specifies how to project (flatten) 3D coords onto a 2D plane. You can think of it as specifying the camera's viewing volume (for an orthographic projection this would be a cuboid). You can generate your rotation matrix, your translation matrix and your proj matrix by using the static methods provided by OpenTK's Matrix4 class (you can take their code for your use).

Comment: @Steve: If you wanna know more, I suggest you write some simple 3D programs in OpenGL to better learn how the transforms work. So read an OpenGL book or tutorial.

Comment: @Steve: You're welcome. Also, look at Matrix4.LookAt from OpenTK - it's a special purpose function that can generate your modelView matrix directly. It's analogous to gluLookAt from OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

For the first few years they were for sale, mass-market graphics processors for PC didn't translate or rotate points at all. Are you required to implement this feature? If not, you may wish to let software do it. Depending on your circumstances, software may be the more sensible route.

If you are required to implement the feature, I'll tell you how they did it in the early days.

The hardware has sixteen floating point registers that represent a 4x4 matrix. The application developer loads these registers with the ModelViewProjection matrix just before rendering a mesh of triangles. The ModelViewProjection matrix is:

Model * View * Projection

Where "Model" is a matrix that brings vertices from "model" coordinates into "world" coordinates, "View" is a matrix that brings vertices from "world" coordinates into "camera" coordinates, and "Projection" is a matrix that brings vertices from "camera" coordinates to "screen" coordinates. Together they bring vertices from "model" coordinates - coordinates relative to the 3D model they belong to - into "screen" coordinates, where you intend to rasterize them as triangles.

Those are three different matrices, but they're multiplied together and the 4x4 result is written to hardware registers.

When a buffer of vertices is to be rendered as triangles, the hardware reads in vertices as [x,y,z] vectors from memory, and treats them as if they were [x,y,z,w] where w is always 1.  It then multiplies each vector by the 4x4 ModelViewProjection matrix to get [x',y',z',w']. If there is perspective (you said there wasn't) then we divide by w' to get perspective [x'/w',y'/w',z'/w',w'/w'].

Then triangles are rasterized with the newly computed vertices. This enables a model's vertices to be in read-only memory if desired, though the model and camera may be in motion.